# Read created headers on result executed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I'm using Asp.Net Core 3.1 as a Rest Api Service. I used memory cache to store result after calling actions,

The problem is i created custom headers on actions before return the object and i also need to cache this headers, but i cant access it while using OnResultExecuted on action filters

Web api :

```
[CachingResource(Prefixe = CachingPrefixes.Contents)]
[HttpGet("{typeId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int typeId, [FromQuery]GetContentsParams prms)
{
    ApiPagedList<C_ContentLoc> items = await _rep.GetItemsLocPaged(typeId, prms);
    IEnumerable<ContentDto> dto = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ContentDto>>(items);

    Response.AddPaginationHeader(items.CurrentPage, items.PageSize, items.TotalCount, items.TotalPages);

    return Ok(dto);
}
```

Add pagination header extension :

```
public static void AddPaginationHeader(this HttpResponse response, int currentPage, int pageSize, int totalItems, int numberOfPages)
{
    var paginationHeader = new PaginationHeader(currentPage, pageSize, numberOfPages, totalItems);
    //create header object
    var camelCaseFormatter = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    camelCaseFormatter.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    response.Headers.Add("Pagination", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paginationHeader, camelCaseFormatter));
    //give the client access to this header
    response.AddExposeHeader("Pagination");
}
```

Caching resource filter on result executed :

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
{
    if (!isInCache && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cacheKey))
    {
        if (context.Result is OkObjectResult result)
        {
            bool isExist = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Pagination", out StringValues vs);
            if(isExist)
            {
                //no result !
            }
            _cache.Set(cacheKey, result.Value);
            CachingHelper.SaveCacheKeys(Prefixe, cacheKey, _cache);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read `Response` headers, but not `Request`

```
bool isExist = context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.TryGetValue("Pagination", out StringValues vs);
```